# Program to detect a change in color of a single pixel?

Tags: macos, colors, pixel

I want a program that I can input the coordinates of a specific pixel on the screen and, when the color of that pixel changes, something to happen. (music to play, specifically).

I have a macbook and am rather new to programming, any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to get the current image of the screen as pixel data, but when you do, it will be as a primitive array (unsigned char most likely). The array can be in any of multiple different formats, but the most common is 4 byte RGBA, meaning each component gets 1 byte of information. The pixel data is generally laid out like text in a book: left to right, top to bottom.

Let's say your pixel is at location (x, y). In order to get the index of the pixel data, you would need to do the following:

```
int width;       //set to the width of the image
int height;      //set to the height of the image
int index;

//number of bytes per pixel * number of pixels per row * number of rows
index = 4 * width * y;     //get the index of the start of the correct row

//number of bytes per pixel * number of pixels to go across
index += 4 * x;            //get the index of the correct column in the row

// pixels[index] = red byte
// pixels[index + 1] = green byte
// pixels[index + 2] = blue byte
// pixels[index + 3] = alpha byte
// pixels[index - (any number)] = previous pixels
// pixels[index + (any number more than 3)] = future pixels
```

Now that you know how to access the pixel data for a specific pixel, just store the RGBA values for the given pixel at the start of the program and as the program runs, occasionally compare the current color to the stored color (use a timer). When they are different, do something (play music).

Hope this helps!